# Does php file() require fclose() at the end?

Tags: php, function, file-io

Does PHP automatically close the file after a `file();` function, or does it require `fclose();` or similar?

Comment: no you don't have to close with `fclose()`, you just need to call `file()`

Comment: Fopen() requires fclose() at the end.

Comment: you don't need one, there's no handle assigned

Comment: The OS automatically closes files when the process exits. However, if you keep opening files without intermediate process exit, you will run out of handles at some point - classical resource leak. Also, when serving pages using Apache, there is no intermediate process exit, but I'm pretty sure that PHP does the cleanup for you after serving the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does PHP automatically close the file after a file(); function, or does it require fclose(); or similar?

No, `file()` doesn't require a `fclose()` call. You can see that in the source code of the function that it all ends nice and clean, so you don't have to call `fclose()` or do anything similar, you simple can call `file()`.

[Source code:](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/file.c#L709)

```
/* {{{ proto array file(string filename [, int flags[, resource context]])
   Read entire file into an array */
PHP_FUNCTION(file)
{
    char *filename;
    size_t filename_len;
    char *p, *s, *e;
    register int i = 0;
    char eol_marker = '\n';
    zend_long flags = 0;
    zend_bool use_include_path;
    zend_bool include_new_line;
    zend_bool skip_blank_lines;
    php_stream *stream;
    zval *zcontext = NULL;
    php_stream_context *context = NULL;
    zend_string *target_buf;

    /* Parse arguments */
    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS(), "p|lr!", &filename, &filename_len, &flags, &zcontext) == FAILURE) {
        return;
    }
    if (flags < 0 || flags > (PHP_FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH | PHP_FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | PHP_FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | PHP_FILE_NO_DEFAULT_CONTEXT)) {
        php_error_docref(NULL, E_WARNING, "'" ZEND_LONG_FMT "' flag is not supported", flags);
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }

    use_include_path = flags & PHP_FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH;
    include_new_line = !(flags & PHP_FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    skip_blank_lines = flags & PHP_FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES;

    context = php_stream_context_from_zval(zcontext, flags & PHP_FILE_NO_DEFAULT_CONTEXT);

    stream = php_stream_open_wrapper_ex(filename, "rb", (use_include_path ? USE_PATH : 0) | REPORT_ERRORS, NULL, context);
    if (!stream) {
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }

    /* Initialize return array */
    array_init(return_value);

    if ((target_buf = php_stream_copy_to_mem(stream, PHP_STREAM_COPY_ALL, 0)) != NULL) {
        s = target_buf->val;
        e = target_buf->val + target_buf->len;

        if (!(p = (char*)php_stream_locate_eol(stream, target_buf))) {
            p = e;
            goto parse_eol;
        }

        if (stream->flags & PHP_STREAM_FLAG_EOL_MAC) {
            eol_marker = '\r';
        }

        /* for performance reasons the code is duplicated, so that the if (include_new_line)
         * will not need to be done for every single line in the file. */
        if (include_new_line) {
            do {
                p++;
parse_eol:
                add_index_stringl(return_value, i++, s, p-s);
                s = p;
            } while ((p = memchr(p, eol_marker, (e-p))));
        } else {
            do {
                int windows_eol = 0;
                if (p != target_buf->val && eol_marker == '\n' && *(p - 1) == '\r') {
                    windows_eol++;
                }
                if (skip_blank_lines && !(p-s-windows_eol)) {
                    s = ++p;
                    continue;
                }
                add_index_stringl(return_value, i++, s, p-s-windows_eol);
                s = ++p;
            } while ((p = memchr(p, eol_marker, (e-p))));
        }

        /* handle any left overs of files without new lines */
        if (s != e) {
            p = e;
            goto parse_eol;
        }
    }

    if (target_buf) {
        zend_string_free(target_buf);
    }
    php_stream_close(stream);
}
/* }}} */
```

See at the end 3rd line from the bottom it ends the function nice and clean:

```
php_stream_close(stream);
```