# PHP - too many open files if using `file()`

Tags: php, file, laravel-5, handle

I developed this function which reads N lines from a file and outputs them.

```
public function readLinesFromFile($file, $maxLines, $reverse=false)
{
    $lines = file($file);

    if ($lines == false) {
        echo "Datei '$file' konnte nicht geöffnet werden.";
        return false;
    }
    if ($maxLines > count($lines)) {
        echo "\$maxLines ist größer als die Anzahl der Zeilen in der Datei.";
        return false;
    }

    if ($reverse) {
        $lines = array_reverse($lines);
    }

    $tmpArr = array();

    for ($i=0; $i < $maxLines; $i++) {
        array_push($tmpArr, $lines[$i]);
    }

    if ($reverse) {
        $tmpArr = array_reverse($tmpArr);
    }

    $out = "";
    for ($i=0; $i < $maxLines; $i++) {
        $out .= $tmpArr[$i] . "</br>";
    }

    return $out;
}
```

Everything worked fine, but now of a sudden I get:

> Warning: file(C:_Projekte\selenium.env): failed to open stream: Too
>   many open files in
>   C:_Projekte\selenium\vendor\vlucas\phpdotenv\src\Loader.php on line
>   135

I am using the php method [file](http://php.net/manual/function.file.php).
It does not return a handle but an array. I am not sure wether the handle is closed by the function or not. I can only see its declaration:

```
function file(string $filename, int $flags = 0, $context = null): array {}
```

Is this a PHP Bug or my fault? I know I can increase the limit of open files, but this is not a solution. Should I use another method than `file()`?

---

I am fetching the last 100 Lines of a logfile in a specific interval (each 250 ms). I guess the handles are opened but not closed by `file()`

Comment: Try to use `file_get_contents`

Comment: Why do you think that your method causes error? As I can see error happens in vendor library.

Comment: `C:_Projekte\selenium\vendor\vlucas\phpdotenv\src\Loader.php ` -> doesn't seem to have anything to do with your file. You did hit open files limit, for some reason, but your method doesn't seem to have anything to do with it.

Comment: Can you give a bit more context about what how you interact with `Loader.php` and how you are trying to load `selenium.env`?

Comment: problem is probably in the loop/iterator that calls this method a hundred times

Comment: I am fetching the last 100 Lines of a logfile in a specific interval (each 250 ms). I guess the handles are opened but not closed by `file()`

Comment: Why are you reversing the order of the lines twice, which cancels each other out?
Also why not use `join( '<br>', $tmpArray)` to join the data at the end

Comment: You would be much better off looking at `array_slice()` to extract lines from the array than the way your trying to do it.

Comment: For your last loop - look at `implode()`.

Comment: @vogomatix, it does not cancel each other out. It is needed and works perfectly fine like this.

Comment: Apart from the problem, your method is inefficient. Refer to [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43634225/693806) to see how to efficiently get last 100 lines from file.

Comment: @N.B. did you measured both? The one you postet looks more complicated than mine.

Comment: `file()` [does close the file handle automatically.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29060966)

Comment: @Black - I have. It contains more code, but your method loads *entire* file into an array opposed to the other one which reads only `n` lines starting at the end. If your file has 1GB, `file` method will attempt to load entire gigabyte into an array. That's where your approach fails.

Comment: @N.B. ok thanks this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I've improved the original method with commented out original code...

```php
public function readLinesFromFile($file, $maxLines, $reverse=false)
{
$lines = file($file);

if ($lines == false) {
    echo "Datei '$file' konnte nicht geöffnet werden.";
    return false;
}
if ($maxLines > count($lines)) {
    echo "\$maxLines ist größer als die Anzahl der Zeilen in der Datei.";
    return false;
}

/*
 *** NONE OF THIS IS NEEDED ***

// array_splice better, removes double reverse...
if ($reverse) {
    $lines = array_reverse($lines);
}

// push loop not needed, just use array_splice...
$tmpArr = array();

for ($i=0; $i < $maxLines; $i++) {
    array_push($tmpArr, $lines[$i]);
}

// reverse not needed as array_splice solves this too..
if ($reverse) {
    $tmpArr = array_reverse($tmpArr);
}

// join instead of concatenate loop
$out = "";
for ($i=0; $i < $maxLines; $i++) {
    $out .= $tmpArr[$i] . "</br>";
}

return $out;

*/

$tmpArr = $reverse ?
    array_slice( $lines, -$maxLines) :
    array_slice( $lines, 0, $maxLines);

// don't even need $tmpArr local but will leave it in
return join( '</br>', $tmpArr);


}
```

Comment: I think as they want the last N lines, the first reverse makes the end of the file at the start, it extracts the first N lines and then the second reverse puts them in the correct order.  Instead could do `$tmpArr = array_slice( $lines, -$maxLines);` - I think!

Comment: Yep I did calculate the number of lines, but using a negative value is better, so amended answer

Comment: @vogomatix, thanks for your improved version, very nice and helpful! I tested it and it still works as expected.

Comment: Amazing what you can do whilst waiting for a repository to clone :)